# Is $L=\{1^n2^n3^m : n\neq m\}$ context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Is the language $L=\{1^n2^n3^m : n\neq m\}$ context free?

I checked and it satisfies the pumping lemma (Right?). Does it also satisfy Ogden's lemma, or any other test for being non-context free?

Comment: Indeed, it seems that Ogden's Lemma is the right approach to show the language is not context-free. See here:  https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/162133/4287 (apart from the simple change in symbols)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language is not context free, and indeed Ogden's Lemma can be used to show so. See the answer in the following [duplicate](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/162133/162601).